# how to setting argument with maven kapt

Tags: maven, kapt

How to set in maven with `kotlin-maven-plugin`?
Here is gradle script:

```
kapt{
    arguments {
        arg("codegen.output", project.file('src/main/generated').path)
        arg("kapt.kotlin.generated", project.file('src/main/generated').path)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<annotationProcessorArgs>
    <processorArg>                     
        codegen.output=${project.basedir}/src/main/generated
    </processorArg>
</annotationProcessorArgs>
```